# Can someone explain what an OAuth Response Token/TokenSecret are used for?

Tags: authentication, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm playing around with adding user authentication on my website using OAuth. I'm using Twitter as the website to authenticate against.

When I *accept* the app on the Twitter site, I get bounced back to my website perfectly. Then I need to do something with the `Tokens` that come back. Looking at some demo code, the code stores the `response.Token` and the `response.TokenSecret` in memory (which is NOT recommended). It's recommended to store these in a database or some persistence storage place.

Why?

What are they used for?

Are they associated to any users at all? I don't understand the relationship with the workflow and also with users.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should your application require access to a user's protected Twitter resources it will have to use the user's info (access token & token secret) along with your application's info (consumer key and consumer secret.) If you store the user's info in a persistent storage space and you share this and your consumer secret with the world then a malicious hacker can spam your user's account.

Answer (score 0):

A secure system should promise you

1. confidentiality - nobody reads your communication in transit
2. integrity - nobody sabotages your message in transit without your detecting it
3. authentication - the sender of the message is not an impostor

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_testing

**--disclaimer: I dont know the details, this is not authoritative--**

The SSL/TLS over which you send your messages (including OAuth protocol messages) helps with 1 and 2 and authenticating the service provider (certificates). The pair of token and token secret helps in authenticating you with public key cryptography. The token secret ensures that only the consumer app can decode the message.

If there is a function **verify(token,tok_secret)** the tok_secret is never sent, only used to decode/verify the reply at the client-side.

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/encryption3.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography